# Substitute, Print and Delete lines in file

Tags: sed, scripting

I'm using sed to do the following:

- Match pattern (eg: line starting with `#`)
- Substitute match (eg: substitute the `#` char at the start to nothing/remove it)
- Print to stdout (eg: print the resulting subtitution to stdout, since we're using `-i`)
- Delete match (eg: delete the whole line that contained the `#` char at the start of the line)

This is done on a file, and as such, `sed` wouldn't output to stdout when used with the `-i` flag, unless I use the following [trick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/108479/409852):

```bsh
sed -i -e 's/^\(#\)/\1/w /dev/stdout' -e '/^#/d' test
```

on a file called `test`, with the following example content:

```
#this
#is
a
test
```

The above work for everything, *except* substitution...
Here the one implementing substitution (where I try to delete the `#` character before printing it to stdout):

```bsh
sed -i -e 's/^\(#\)//w /dev/stdout' -e '/^#/d' test
```

This is similar to above, except I replaced `\1` with `//` so it delete `#` instead of printing the whole line...

Problem is, the last one doesn't work in *deleting* the line, and instead only substitute and print. The first one does work for everything except substitution (eg: removing the `#` sign at the start of the line)

Why isn't this working (the second attempt that is, first one work except it doesn't delete the `#` char)?

Comment: You make an effort to substitute something in a line that starts with a #, then you want to delete it. This is like polishing and filling up your car before sending it to the junkyard. Why not just delete it without substituting it?

Comment: ...Because I need the output *while* also deleting said line in said file? I don't think you always need to specify the lengthy reasons why something need/is to be done, especially when there "already": 1. a possibility it can be done easily (or not), 2. work done/trials/errors by the one who asked, 3. Essentially, I already explained the reason why (eg: using `-i` prevent the output from being shown on stdout, unlike when not using `-i`...) :) @berndbausch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first expression `s/^\(#\)//w /dev/stdout` removes the thing that the second one `/^#/d` would have matched.

You could instead use

```
sed -i -e '/^#/{s///w /dev/stdout' -e 'd}' test
```

ex.

```
$ cat test
#this
#is
a
test

$ sed -i -e '/^#/{s///w /dev/stdout' -e 'd}' test
this
is

$ cat test
a
test
```

Answer (score 1):

With `GNU awk`:

```
awk  -i inplace '{if (/^#/) {sub(/^#/, "");arr[++i]=$0;} else print}END{for (a in arr) print arr[a]}' input
```

The option `-i` or `--include` is used to include an `awk` source library `inplace`.

About `inplace` read [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Inplace.html) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496187/469418).

> The inplace extension emulates GNU sed's `-i` option, which performs "in-place" editing of each input file.

`if (/^#/)` this sees if there is a line starting with `#`. If found `sub()` replces `#` with an empty string. And now substituted `$0` is taken and an array `arr` is created. This array is printed in `END` block so this is printed on screen. Other lines being printed(in `main` block) are sent to file by `inplace`.

```
$ awk  -i inplace '{if (/^#/) {sub(/^#/, "");arr[++i]=$0;} else print}END{for (a in arr) print arr[a]}' input
this
is

$ cat input
a
test
```